# Weird overflow issue on Chrome where element is causing horizontal overflow even with overflow-x: auto

Tags: html-table, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

Page in question is [here](https://www.swiftsalary.com/best-paid-survey-apps/)

The overflow can be seen on mobile only (e.g. iPhone SE) on Chrome browser. Issue doesn't happen on Firefox.

The issue is with the horizontal scroll table, shown here:

[picture of the horizontal scroll table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n26G7.png)

If you remove the white-space: nowrap tag from the  table.hscroll-table selector, the overflow goes away and the horizontal scroll works properly. Otherwise, the horizontal scroll works, but there's also overflow on the entire page, enabling horizontal scrolling throughout the whole page and a bad user experience.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Is it a Chrome bug?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can remove the white-space: nowrap to fix the issue, but that makes the table design worse.

Weirdly enough, the issue only seems to be with the td tags. If I add white-space: nowrap to the header cells only, there's no unwanted overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the problem was because of the screen reader text that was being generated within the table by the rating icons.

I set the screen reader text to display: none as a temporary fix and now display the text right beside the rating instead.